# Why using `System.Timers.Timer` can interfere the whole performance?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm using a method which is called for 2 timers as their elapsed event handlers and also this method is called in the constructor of my class. The body of that method is mainly in

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
 { ... }));
```

I'm having some anomalies. What is better to use instead of a timer?

Comment: Perhaps you could describe these anomalies, and give us more information such as what's happening in the body of the delegate and how often your timer is being scheduled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've asked a couple of questions in the comment to the question, but to address:

> I'm having some anomalies. What is better to use instead of a timer?

If you want to do something periodically *in the `Dispatcher` thread*, use [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) instead. Then you don't need to marshal *back* to the UI thread, as the timer will "tick" in the `Dispatcher` thread already.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how short the interval of the timers are and how much you are doing in the elapsed events. In addition there is a change to the UI thread every time one of the timers elapses.